# Cant access to my nfs server (access denied by server while mounting...)

Tags: nfs

What do I have to do?

I tried to mount my NFS share with FreeNAS but it does not work. I get the notification:

```
 access denied by server while mounting...
```

[image]

I'm new to Ubuntu, so please try to explain your answers simply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain **how** you are trying to mount it, plus the output of the command `showmount -e 192.168.xxx.xxx` where 192.168.xxx.xxx is replaced  by the IP address of your NAS

Comment: @steeldriver did it

Comment: Well, assuming `/mnt/IT-Administrator/Share` is a valid export from your NAS (it would still be good to see the output of the `showmount` command I posted), your error just seems to be in the syntax of the command - you need a colon after the hostname or host IP i.e. `192.168.1.152:/mnt/IT-Administrator/Share`

Answer (score 0):

As @steeldriver mentioned, colon missing, also telling the mount command what type you are passing, as in:

mount **-t nfs** 162.168.1.152:/mnt/IT-Administrator/Share /home

Comment: [edit, removed the following to try and fit wesite ethos] 
Obviously Sudo needed if you are logged in as a user when you try
Also maybe better to mount it to /home/USERNAMEHERE and if works, maybe add it to /etc/fstab for future?

not sure if you already fixed it @neverbesuccesfulllperson...

Not an expert, and came here for some answers myself, but hope the below helps...